# Illustrator: how to get this halftone effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I recently came across this picture and would like to replicate the effect. I have tried Illustrator's halftone effects, but the dots are too tidily arranged and I prefer it to be random sizes and positions.

[image]

Comment: Most likely a plugin or a totally different software.

Comment: Well you could do this in a programming/mathematics system like say mathematica. Would that be okay for you

Comment: Ooki dooki,  made a test its not much of a coding job just slow. Heres a [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf2F2.png). The brighter the pixel the higher likelyhood of making round dot. Yes its vector but i can not ship the file easily.

Answer (score 1):

I literally see myself drawing this manually. I don't deny the fact that (Just as Lucian said) this might be done in some other software or with a plugin but just look at it.

This can totally be done with a custom pattern brush (just repeating circles) for the main shape and hand drawing some of the particles.

> When I initially said **drawing by hand** I didn't mean it literally. Just create a
>   custom brush with dots, use the Pen Tool to give the main shape and
>   apply that brush. Then simply click/tap with a mouse/tablet-pen to
>   create the rest of the dots.

Comment: Call me a luddite but I'd find this so much quicker to hand draw on paper. Stippled patterns are something that a stylus is so much slower at than traditional ink as the beginning and end of a line is typically the moment where a stylus can get a little sloppy with precision. To ask it to rapidly stop start over the course of a drawing is something that will ultimately find yourself going a little slower to compensate. A fine tipped ink pen would sail through this (relatively).

Comment: @biscuitstack When I say drawing by hand I don't mean it literally. Just create a custom brush with dots, use the Pen Tool to give the main shape and apply that brush. Then simply click/tap with a mouse/tablet-pen to create the rest of the dots.

Comment: @biscuitstack Updated my answer to make it clear what I mean.

Comment: Well doing a script that does this isnt necceserily hard just a bit tricky.

Comment: @Alin Understood, thanks. As a follow on: if I got this in as a brief I wouldn't hesitate to do with an ink pen anyway. I'd be dubious of any automation (even a well made stippled brush pattern) coming close to the aesthetic of an ink pen for a job like this. Preference, I know, and I don't doubt there's some clever automation that can do a reasonable job. I think Tom Waits once asked why would someone spend all the time and money emulating the noise of a garbage can being kicked over as a drum effect when it's often quicker and sounds nicer just to kick over a garbage can.

Comment: @biscuitstack yeah its like all those people who want to get tthe effect of being printed with a bad printer, print with bad printer. But seriously though if you have this on a computer and you need to make a change your much better off.

Comment: Honestly.... I **would** *"draw by hand"*. Maybe 30 minutes to an hour by hand as opposed to  several hours to configure a brush, adjust the brush, draw paths that the brush works well on, adjust the paths... expand areas, mask, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the closest look with two layers:
1. Duplicate artwork set to Color Dodge in the Transparency palette.
2. Artwork with Effect>Pixelate>Pointilize applied.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is best to do this initially in Photoshop. Then convert to bitmap (50% threshold). You can then import the bitmap into illustrator and change to any spot colour you wish.